# to_json is slow when using the :include option for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

For example, I have two documents

```
class Task
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :person
end
```

and

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  has_one :stage
end
```

and I have a method in my controller

```
def index
  tasks = Task.all
  render :json => tasks.to_json(:include => :person)
end
```

Looking at the queries generated, I see it looking up the person for each task (there are 3 tasks currently)

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=pipeline_development collection=tasks selector={} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 fields=nil (0.3619ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=pipeline_development collection=people selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"50f12eb2cce8b43b05000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 fields=nil (0.1998ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=pipeline_development collection=people selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"50f12eb2cce8b43b05000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 fields=nil (0.3881ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=pipeline_development collection=people selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"50f12eb2cce8b43b05000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 fields=nil (0.2272ms)
```

This can actually add up (the time for each lookup in my database is actually 25ms instead of 0.3ms) and lead to unreasonable slowness.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I tried eager loading

```
def index
  tasks = Task.all.includes(:person)
  render :json => tasks.to_json(:include => :person)
end
```

but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment and not a solution since I haven't tried it yet, but you might want to check out [this json gem](http://flori.github.com/json/), it's a gem that was built specifically to solve the problem of `to_json` being too slow. I'm going to try it now and will post an answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/ohler55/oj and it resulted in a significant improvement in the processing time. You might want to try that out if the gem you linked to doesn't work out.